# SciPy equivalent of np.minimum.outer

Tags: scipy, outer-join

I need to do the outer product of two (large) sparse vectors, taking a minimum of the values instead of multiplication. I need an efficient way to perform this.
The build-in point-wise multiplication takes 30ms, and my (naive) code takes 5 minutes

```
%%timeit -r 1
# c1, c2 are .nonzero of sparse vector
minl = lil_matrix((c1.shape[1], c2.shape[1]))
for i1 in c1.nonzero()[1]:
    for i2 in c2.nonzero()[1]:
        minl[i1, i2] = min(c1[0, i1], c2[0, i2])
```

Comment: You are assuming that the nonzero values in the vectors are positive, correct?  I ask because your naive code does not handle negative values correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification - yes, all values are positive and normalised to 0-1

Comment: So are `c1,c2` (0,n) shaped sparse matrices (which format)?  So your `outer` combines two 1d arrays to a make 2d?  `c1.nonzero()[1]` converts `c1` to COO format and returns the `col` attribute.  Without getting into the details, I suspect working with `sparse` adds a lot of unnecessary overhead.  `lil` may be the best format for iterative assignment, but it is still more expensive then simple dict or list assignments.  Or consider creating the COO style input arrays (appended lists) from the `min` calc, and making the matrix from those.

Comment: It is correct; I want to do an outer join of two sparse vectors (extracted from csr_matrix) to get a 2d matrix. I need to keep the matrices sparse as the dimensions are (6Mx6M), and I need the result to be a sparse matrix for the downstream tasks (multiplication with other sparse matrices)
The same operation is performed by v1.T * v2 very efficiently in SciPy, but the operation is multiplication, not the minimum value that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I should insist on a [mcve], but let's make a guess as to what's a reasonable sample:

```
In [107]: from scipy import sparse    
In [108]: c1 = sparse.random(1,100,.2,'csr')    
In [109]: c2 = sparse.random(1,100,.2,'csr')

In [110]: def foo(c1,c2):
     ...:     minl = sparse.lil_matrix((c1.shape[1], c2.shape[1]))
     ...:     for i1 in c1.nonzero()[1]:
     ...:         for i2 in c2.nonzero()[1]:
     ...:             minl[i1, i2] = min(c1[0, i1], c2[0, i2])
     ...:     return minl
     ...: 

In [111]: LL1 = foo(c1,c2)

In [112]: LL1
Out[112]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 400 stored elements in List of Lists format>
```

### dense with broadcasting

For dense arrays a simple element-wise minimum for matching array lengths is:

```
In [118]: np.minimum(c1.A,c2.A).shape
Out[118]: (1, 100)
```

and with broadcasting we can do an 'outer' minimum:

```
In [119]: np.minimum(c1.T.A,c2.A).shape
Out[119]: (100, 100)
```

and that matches your iterative answer:

```
In [122]: np.allclose(np.minimum(c1.T.A,c2.A),LL1.A)
Out[122]: True
```

And comparative times:

```
In [123]: timeit LL1 = foo(c1,c2)
37.8 ms ± 240 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [124]: timeit np.minimum(c1.T.A,c2.A)
257 µs ± 3.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

But sparse doesn't do broadcasting.

I suggested building a coo matrix in the loop

Another possibility is to 'replicate' `c1.T` and `c2` so we can do the `minimum`.

### expanded sparse matrices

I can expand the matrics by multiplying by the appropriate sparse ones matrix:

```
In [135]: (c1.T*sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((1,100)))).minimum(sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((100,1))*c2))
Out[135]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 400 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [136]: np.allclose(_.A,LL1.A)
Out[136]: True
```

That times at

```
1.91 ms ± 15.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

and packaged neatly

```
def foo1(c1,c2):
    On1 = sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((1,c2.shape[1])))
    On2 = sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((c1.shape[1],1)))
    cc1 = c1.T*On1
    cc2 = On2*c2
    return cc1.minimum(cc2)
```

### List iteration

Here's a "pure python" iterative version

```
def foo0(c1,c2):
    data, row, col = [],[],[]
    cc = c1.tocoo(); d1 = cc.data.tolist(); l1 = cc.col.tolist()
    cc = c2.tocoo(); d2 = cc.data.tolist(); l2 = cc.col.tolist()
    for i,i1 in enumerate(l1):
        for j,i2 in enumerate(l2):
            data.append(min(d1[i],d2[j]))
            row.append(i1)
            col.append(i2)
    minl = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row,col)), shape=(c1.shape[1],c2.shape[1]))
    return minl

In [170]: foo0(c1,c2)
Out[170]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 400 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [171]: np.allclose(_.A,LL1.A)
Out[171]: True

In [172]: timeit foo0(c1,c2)
576 µs ± 11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

We don't have to iterate on the `c2`, instead using array methods

```
def foo02(c1,c2):
    data, row, col = [],[],[]
    cc = c1.tocoo(); d1 = cc.data.tolist(); l1 = cc.col.tolist()
    cc = c2.tocoo(); d2 = cc.data; l2 = cc.col
    for i,i1 in enumerate(l1):
        data.append(np.minimum(d1[i],d2))
        row.append([i1]*l2.shape[0])
        col.append(l2)
    data = np.hstack(data)
    row = np.hstack(row)
    col = np.hstack(col)
    minl = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row,col)), shape=(c1.shape[1],c2.shape[1]))
    return minl
```

This has a modest time improvement on `foo0`.  It may scale better.

Your suggested change

```
def foo11(c1,c2):
    On1 = c2.copy(); On1.data[:] = 1
    On2 = c1.T.copy(); On2.data[:] = 1
    cc1 = c1.T*On1
    cc2 = On2*c2
    return cc1.minimum(cc2)
```

1.21 ms ± 14 µs per loop

Comment: Thank you so much; expanding with ones is a smart trick - it is still several times slower than simple multiplication and takes 120 GB of memory on my data, but it works!

Comment: I've managed to speed it up and reduce memory my constructing the sparse matrix with

On1 = v1.copy()
On1.data = np.ones(On1.shape[1])

instead of 

On1 = sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((1,c2.shape[1])))